# Can you have more than one 'best' of something?

Tags: semantics, superlative-degree

For example, can you say 'I have more than one best friend' and is that grammatically correct given that these friends are equally good?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with talking about your _best friends_ or the worlds _highest mountains_, but that does not imply that the actual top-position is shared by two or more of them.

Comment: This is not a matter of grammar. You can say that you have more than one best friend and be completely grammatical. You can also say that you have more than one best pelvis and be grammatical, even though you obviously have only one pelvis. What you’re asking about is logic and semantics; not grammar.

Comment: If you are really asking if it's *grammatically* correct, then the answer is that you can put absolutely any adjective at all there. The grammar does not change one bit.

Answer (score 4):

The term *best* is a category. How many units fit in the category depends on context.

If there is a contest, like a dog show, there may be a *best* in each breed, and a *best in show*. Overall, the show would issue several *best* medals.

Stores often categorize products based on features. They may label several of a given type of item *good*, several *better* and several *best*. Whether they have one or more in each category mostly depends on the depth of their offerings.

The term *best* when applied colloquially is a high end compliment, not intended to formally rank a person with regard to all friends or aquaintences. It is likely that your spouse would not be annoyed or feel diminished if you thank a friend for an assist by saying

> *You're the best!*

As to *best friend*, it again depends on context.  You might say

> *We're the best of friends.*

There may be several individuals you could say that about without confusion.

However, when you say

> *This is my best friend*

most US speakers would probably think that the identified individual was likely the single person you felt closest to (aside from relatives, who might or might not be labeled *best friends*).